# Microsoft CRM Development

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am new to Dynamic CRM. I need to learn it asap so I can modify some custom code. I have inherited project files that have web pages and web service files. I do not see a solution file. How do I go about opening the project to figure out what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can open project files directly with Visual Studio (eg. .csproj). If you don't have any of those files if may be because you're code is a Visual Studio "website". To open it, open Visual Studio, File -> Open -> Website (Shift-Alt-O)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Blank Solution in Visual Studio.

Right-click the solution - Choose "Add Existing Project" or "Add existing website" if your website doesn't have a project file

Add each project file individually